# Сериализация List Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, monodevelop

Не получается сериализовать класс при помощи `JsonUtility.ToJson()`.
В файле всегда пустые скобки.

Класс:

```
[Serializable]
public class DataModel
{
   public bool IsLevelCompleted;
   public int TopScore;
   public int LevelNumber;
}
```

Добавляю в `List<DataModel>`

```
gameData.Add (new DataModel ()
{
    IsLevelCompleted = true,
    LevelNumber = LevelSelector.SelectedLevel,
    TopScore = this.Score   
});

string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(gameData);
```

Comment: Распространенная ошибка. Измените поля на свойства.

Comment: @Nikita, тоже самое, `{}` все что есть в файле

Comment: Какой результат вы хотите видеть в итоге?

Comment: @KitScribe, хотелось бы увидеть сериализованные данные в файле

Comment: @SmiLe полностью покажите ваш скрипт. Если скриптов несколько, укажите их имена. Кусками не очень понятно что и где, куда и как вы добавляете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы сериализатора Unity, согласно [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html), поля действительно должны быть полями, причём `public`, всё правильно.
Попробуйте для списка создать отдельную обёртку, так должно работать:

```
[Serializable]
public class DataModel
{
   public bool IsLevelCompleted;
   public int TopScore;
   public int LevelNumber;
}

[Serializable]
public class ListHolder
{
    public List<DataModel> dataModels;
}
```

---

Идея взята с [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/5472058) ответа на enSO, почитайте, действительно хороший ответ.

Comment: Я правильно вас понял? Я обновил вопрос, но в таком случае записывается  `{"dataModel":[{}]}`

Comment: @SmiLe одиночные элементы сериализуются? Только с листом такие проблемы? И ещё, вы последнюю версию Юнити используете? Вы правильно поняли, и если этот вариант не работает, то можете удалить этот кусок кода из вопроса и мы подумаем каким образом можно по другому решить проблему.

Comment: dm тоже не сериализуется, в string json записывается {}. Версия юнити 5.6.03f

Comment: Нет, один объект все таки сериализуется

Answer (score 0):

Штатные коллекции действительно не поддерживаются, как и сложные типы. Но в данном случае обертывание List в свой класс действительно должно помочь:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    [Serializable]
    public class DataModel {
        public bool IsLevelCompleted;
        public int TopScore;
        public int LevelNumber;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class GameData {
        public List<DataModel> Items = new List<DataModel> ();
    }

    void Start () {
        var gameData = new GameData ();
        gameData.Items.Add (new DataModel () {
            IsLevelCompleted = true,
            LevelNumber = 1,
            TopScore = 123
        });
        gameData.Items.Add (new DataModel () {
            IsLevelCompleted = false,
            LevelNumber = 2,
            TopScore = 234
        });
        Debug.Log (JsonUtility.ToJson (gameData));
    }
}
```

В консоль выводится следующее:

```
{"Items":[
    {"IsLevelCompleted":true,"TopScore":123,"LevelNumber":1},
    {"IsLevelCompleted":false,"TopScore":234,"LevelNumber":2}
]}
```

То есть сериализация нескольких элементов поддерживается без проблем. Unity 5.6.0f3.